# agregar elementos a un objeto en state (consulta de firebase) para hacer un scrol infinito o paginar las consultas

Tags: firebase, reactjs, scroll, paginación

realice una consulta a firebase y guarde los datos (limit 5) en el state (react) ahora realizo la consulta de los siguientes 5 productos pero quiero agregarlos a los ya guardados en el state ,para poder mostrar un total de 10 productos y así sucesivamente ,15 ,20 ,25.

```
const firstSearch = this.props.firebase.PdtoRef().orderBy("creationDate", "desc").limit(limitProduct);
        firstSearch.get().then(querySnapshot => {
            this.setState({
                lastVisible: querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1]  ,
            })
            const lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1];
            console.log("last", lastVisible);
            const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

            this.setState({
                query:querySnapshot.docs,
                products: data,
            })
        });
```

He intentado con push pero parece que se des estructura el objeto y los componentes de card que desarrolle para mostrar cada producto ya no pueden leer la data....

como actualizo el state pero conservando los datos anteriores en el mismo objeto? ...intente

```
 const allProducts = this.state.products ;
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => allProducts.push(doc.data()));
            this.setState({
                query:querySnapshot.docs,
                products: data,
            })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

por si a alguin le sirve y esta buscando una paginacion incremental esta fue mi solucion

```
const allProducts = this.state.products ;
        querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => allProducts.push(doc.data()));
            this.setState({
                query:querySnapshot.docs,
                products: allProducts,
            })
        console.log(allProducts);
```

Cree un constante para todos los productos y con .push le agregue los nuevos datos , después actualice el estado con la constante que tenia todos los productos